# Should I return true in a method that casts null from one object type to another?

Tags: c#, null, type-casting, return-type

I'm writing a very simple extension method that attempts to cast objects from one type to another. The intent of having this method is very similar to `Int32.TryParse(string, out int)`, which allows the user to see 1) if the conversion succeeded, and 2) what the converted object is, all in one line.

Because this method will deal exclusively with class objects, it's possible that the object to be cast is actually null. Null can be cast to any nullable type (at least that's what it looks like based on my testing), so technically the method would always succeed in that situation. On the other hand, trying to convert null doesn't serve a lot of purpose and is usually a sign of things gone wrong. Therefore, my question is: in the case of the supplied object being null, should I return true (the cast succeeded) or false (did not succeed)?

This is (more or less) the method in question:

```
public static bool TryGetAs<T>(this object obj, out T output) where T : class
{
    output = null;
    if (obj == null)
        return [true or false];

    output = obj as T;
    return output != null;
}
```

Comment: `in the case of the supplied object being null, should I return true (the cast succeeded) or false (did not succeed)?` -- Did the cast actually succeed or not?

Comment: Why would it be a sign that something is wrong to try to cast `null` to another type?  Plenty of the casts I make are on potentially `null` values.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest very much *avoiding* this pattern.  Methods like `int.TryParse` are a real pain to deal with.  Virtually any time I would have to deal with any method of this pattern I have to refactor it into a method that actually returns the parsed value instead of using `out`.

Comment: Note that you can't call an extension method on a null object anyway.  You'll get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Servy: That only works if you can agree on some returned object that indicates parse failure, or some acceptable default.  Otherwise, it's not the same semantics.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You absolutely *can* call an extension method on a `null` object.  It will not NRE.

Comment: @Servy: Maybe, on an actual `object` type.  Never actually tried that.  It won't work for any other type, even a nullable one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure.  You're right that technically there is less information in there, my point was that, in my experiences, the entirety of that information is virtually never needed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It will work for *any* type.  You could never write an invocation of any extension method that would ever NRE.  (Obviously code in the implementation of the method could NRE and it could bubble up, but the invocation of the extension method itself can never NRE.)

Comment: @Servy: Then why the hell does it fail in my own code?  Shit, now you're going to make me prove something I already know.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Remember that extensions methods are just syntactic sugar for static method calls.  There is no virtual dispatch.  `someVariable.SomeExtensionMethod();` is transformated by the compiler into the morale equavalent of `ClassExtensionMethodIsIn.SomeExtensionMethod(someVariable);`, which obviously is never going to NRE.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Presumably you're calling instance methods of the object in the body of the extension method, and *those* calls are throwing and bubbling up.  That, or you have an instance method, not an extension method.  Some people also explicitly null check the parameter and throw an NRE (despite it being poor practice to manually throw an NRE) if the first argument of an extension method is `null`; you could be doing that.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps I'm trying to cram too many validation checks into one method, but the idea is that the if user didn't check for null before the call, they won't know if the resulting null is due to the `TryGetAs` failing to convert, or if it's because the object was null in the first place (since without the check this method will return false in both cases).

Comment: @MageXy So then fix the implementation of the method.  It should return `obj is T`.  That will only ever return true when the value can be stored in a variable of type `T`.

Comment: @Servy: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33929423#33929423

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to what your clients want, and try to provide an abstraction that is useful.  And if you are your own client, try to think critically about what you want as a client rather than as the implementer.

I would assert that at the point someone calls this they are now only interested in whether the item provides the API of the type (which null doesn't).

If you return `true` for null, your clients are IMNSHO very likely to have to do their own null check in conjunction with, and either before or after using, your method.  Only in vary rare cases will they not need their own null check.

If you return false, they won't have to do their own null check.

Still, have a look at how clients use the function, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Now you're violating the single responsibility principle though.  You're both checking if the type is compatible and you're also checking if the value is not null.  You also assume that `null` is never a sensible value, an assumption that may or may not be the case (or rather, may or may not *always* be the case).

Comment: @Servy: That's not what a "responsibility" is.

Comment: @Servy, well, that's interesting.  There's hardly enough responsibility here to merit a method, and it is certainly not an API or encapsulation.  Further, I guess the built-in `as` violates that as well, since null -> null even though it is compatible.

Comment: It's too bad that Bob Martin elevated "SRP" to a "Principle" when he didn't even make "responsibility" a well-defined term.  I've seen enough hand-wringing over that principle to fill a large book, especially from developers who don't know their primary language well enough yet to properly evaluate their code in terms of SRP.

Comment: @Servy, however, perhaps the OP is best served by popping up a bit and doing something more domain oriented rather than working at such a low and linguistic level.

Comment: @RobertHarvey All right, I'll take the bait, how do you define it?  Oh, and have you tested whether or not an extension method invocation can throw an NRE yet?

Comment: @Servy but if you have to do a null check multiple times, you're violating the DRY principle. I'd argue that the responsibility you're performing in such a case is the responsibility, "provide a valid interface", not "check if value is null AND cast it".

Comment: @Servy: I can't reproduce the problem right now.  Don't conflate my apparent inability to use extension methods properly with my clear and unambiguous perception that, when someone talks about SRP on these sites, roughly 80 percent of the time their focus is misplaced.  That I'm wrong about the one doesn't mean I'm also wrong about the other.

Comment: @KevinFee Why would you need to do a null check multiple times?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Okay, sounds good.  Now, what about my usage do you feel was inappropriate (not talking about any of the other usages out there on the site; I couldn't comment on how many of them are or are not sensible).

Comment: @Servy That's the central conceit of the answer. Every time you call this function (and it returned true on null) you would ALSO have to check for null. Assuming this function is used more than once, then that's multiple times you have to check for null - with every call.

Comment: @Servy: My go-to example is a CRUD class.  You don't say "it violates SRP because you're performing four different operations," do you?  It has a single responsibility: CRUD.  Most of the misgivings around SRP eventually resolve to "each class should only do one thing," which I'm pretty sure is not what Uncle Bob really meant.

Comment: @KevinFee Then I guess I just don't agree with that premise then.  I can't imagine that you'd *always* need to be checking for null whenever performing a cast, given that I very rarely need to check for null explicitly when using normal casts, which is effectively what this method exists to represent.

Comment: @Servy That's what the OP needs to figure out. I, personally, would either rely on InvalidCastException and NullReferenceException or use "as T if != null". But if I were to make the OP's function, I would assume that the user is looking for a valid reference that can be used without exception in the true branch. If that's what the OP wants, they should return false in the case of null.

Comment: @KevinFee The way the OP worded their requirements is that they want to know if the conversion succeeded or not, and the conversion *does* succeed.  This would imply that they want to store the value in a location of the target type, rather than that they necessarily want to *act* on the value immediately.  Of course, even if they *did* want to act on it, they could simply use the null propagation member access operators, making the need for a method such as this rather moot.

Answer (score 1):

If your input parameter is null you are not able to decide what is the right return value. Any return value would be as good as the other. It doesn't matter if it is null, true, false or "foobar".

Getting a special type of object from an arbitrary object is really weired. I really doubt the usecase. The point is that your generic method uses a language specific resolution that only works with related types... or at least it only makes sense with related types...

The difference between your method and the parse-method is: the int parse method provides a concrete algorithm to resolve the integer from a String. This algorithm is semantically well-defined.

Your algorithm may be technically well-defined but not semantically. You can easily see that if you try to put in an object of a custom type of yours and you want to return a String. I cannot imagine how this can make sense. How can this method do better than a toString method on the source object itself? The provided algorithm has no semantics.

So if you make the method generic and your algorithm does only make sense for SOME inputs and SOME outputs why should I confuse users of this method by pretending that it is doing beneficial stuff?

Avoid such kind of methods that pretend generic but are not.